# Update return 0 even there is no this id in table

Tags: c++, sql, sqlite

I am using sqlite in visual studio.

I am trying to update a record which does not exist in my table.

Here is the code:

```
const char* sqlUpdateTable = "UPDATE MyTable SET name = '25th' WHERE id = 25;";

rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sqlUpdateTable, NULL, NULL, &error);
if (rc)
{
    cerr << "Error executing SQLite3 statement: " << sqlite3_errmsg(db) << endl << endl;
    sqlite3_free(error);
}
else
{
    cout << "Updated MyTable." << endl << endl;
}
```

I will always see "Updated MyTable". However, it didn't.

Comment: *I am trying to update a record which does not exist in my table.* That makes no sense. You can't update something that doesn't exist. Use `INSERT` to add a new record if that's what you're really wanting to do.

Comment: An UPDATE query will run just fine if no records match its condition.  In this case it will update zero records.  Is there a way you can get the number of updated records back from the UPDATE statement?

Comment: I need to update a specific record, ex: PRIMARY KEY id = 10, if this record doesn't exist, I need to insert it.

Comment: Why not call `sqlite_changes()` to find out how many rows were affected by the previous query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your *actual* question:

> I need to update a specific record, ex: PRIMARY KEY id = 10, if this record doesn't exist, I need to insert it.

Modern versions of Sqlite support Postgres-style [UPSERT](https://sqlite.org/lang_UPSERT.html) notation:

```
INSERT INTO myTable(id, name) VALUES (25, '25th') ON CONFLICT (id) DO UPDATE SET name = '25th';
```

Assuming `id` is a primary key or unique column, this will either insert a new row or update the name column of an existing row with that `id`.

Older versions can use [INSERT OR REPLACE](https://sqlite.org/lang_insert.html) to get something similar:

```
INSERT INTO myTable(id, name) VALUES (25, 'Original Name');
-- At some later point...
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO myTable(id, name) VALUES (25, '25th');
```

From the [REPLACE conflict resolution](https://sqlite.org/lang_conflict.html) documentation:

> When a UNIQUE or PRIMARY KEY constraint violation occurs, the REPLACE algorithm deletes pre-existing rows that are causing the constraint violation prior to inserting or updating the current row and the command continues executing normally.

Answer (score -1):

Try to check if state is NOT OK

```
if( rc != SQLITE_OK )
```