# How insert data into table by C variable?

Tags: c++, sql, sqlite

I want to INSERT data INTO table, the data are C variables.

Here is my current code:

```
const char* sqlUpdateTable = "INSERT INTO MyTable 
                                          VALUES(25, 'String1', 'String2')
                                       ON CONFLICT (id) 
                                       DO 
                                         UPDATE SET name = 'New String';";
```

Actually, not only the 'String1', 'String2' and 'New String' need to be variable but the id is also the C/C++ variable.

id is long.

String1 is double.

String2 is int.

Thanks.

Comment: Formatting SQL queries by hand like you are asking is dangerous. You should really use a dedicated SQL library to handle the escaping for you.

Comment: If I recall from [another recent question of yours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56469927/update-return-0-even-there-is-no-this-id-in-table), you are using sqlite.  You should use its interface for [prepared statements](https://sqlite.org/c3ref/stmt.html) to achieve this, along with correctly (_and safely!!_) binding data.

Comment: Formatting SQL queries -> I don't get it, do you mean using const char* as a string to call sqlite3_exec()? I see this from google, any other better way?

Comment: Sometimes the escaping changes over time (to properly escape new sequences), so using the escaping routines works much better than trying to mimic the escaping routines yourself.  Much better future proofing to use the (whichever) supplied SQL escaping routines.

Comment: Why you don't want to use odbc drivers, you will get BIND parameter functions, using which you can execute queries with those parameters. The parameters can be anything like string, integer etc..

Comment: You shouldn't be using `sqlite3_exec()` for this sort of thing. Use prepared statements. See that earlier link to the documentation. No error and injection prone escaping needed.

Comment: My suggestion is to make a stored procedure and call it by C, it'll also reduce risks of sql-injection, admitting that possibility exists in sqlite.

Answer (score 0):

use sprintf()

```
char buffer [200];
double mydouble = 4.0;
long mylong = 2;
int myint = 4;
int n=sprintf (buffer, "INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES(25, '%f', '%i') ON CONFLICT (%l) DO UPDATE SET name = 'New String';", mydouble, myint , mylong);
```

see:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the way I should do?

```
sqlite3_stmt* res;
const char* sqlInsert = "INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES(NULL, ?, ?);";

sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sqlInsert, -1 , &res, 0);

const char* test1 = "ABC";
const char* test2 = "XYZ";

if (sqlite3_bind_text( res, 1, test1, 3, 0 ) != SQLITE_OK) 
{
    printf("\nError 1.\n");
}
if (sqlite3_bind_text(res, 2, test2, 3, 0) != SQLITE_OK)
{
    printf("\nError 2.\n");
}

int step = sqlite3_step(res);
```